# Como utilizar um subdomínio como se fosse um domínio

Tags: dns

Como posso criar 2 subdomínios via `DNS`?

Eu preciso criar 1 para cada servidor e usá-los como se fosse um domínio.

Eu possuo 2 servidores, um no BR e outro nos EUA.

O que eu quero é fazer isso:

srvbr.meudominio.com -> Apontar para Servidor BR

srveua.meudominio.com -> Apontar para Servidor EUA

Comment: Você precisa acessar seu provedor de DNS e criar dois registros do tipo ADRESS para os respectivos subdomínios e IP dos servidores. Criar CNAME's também serve, mas ai os servidores precisam ter um domínio.

Comment: @Wakim elabora mais seu comentário e transforma em resposta.

Comment: @Renan, feito :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por sugestão do @Renan, irei tentar elaborar melhor minha resposta, apesar de eu não ser expert em DNS :)

Porém há duas formas (que eu saiba), de criar subdomínios para um determinado host. Ou por registros *Address* ou por *CNAME*.

#### 1. Entre no seu provedor de DNS

Lá você poderá criar, atualizar, excluir os registros de DNS. Lembrando que essas alterações, se não me falha a memória, demoram um certo tempo para serem aplicadas (**até 48h**, por sugestão do @brasofilo) porque não depende apenas do seu provedor, o novo registro precisa se propagar entre os *TLD's* de mais alto nível e etc...

Acredito que ao entrar no seu provedor, você irá ver uma tela parecida com essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como as alterações de *TTL (TimeToLive)* influênciam na performance, dado que quando o *TTL* de um registro acaba, é preciso consultar os *TLD's* de mais alto nível, o que pode acarretar em tempo perdido consultando *DNS*, já que o cache do *DNS* é feito baseado no *TTL*.

#### 2. Criando registros do tipo ADDRESS (A)

Se você sabe os *IP's* dos servidores e eles não vão mudar, então basta criar um registro do tipo **A** para cada um com o valor:

```
srvbr.meudominio.com IN A IP.do.Servidor.BR
srveua.meudominio.com IN A IP.do.Servidor.EUA
```

E esperar um certo período para o registro se propagar.

#### 3. Criando registros do tipo CNAME

Os registros do tipo *CNAME* não aceitam *IP's*, eles são alias ("atalhos") para domínios. Isso é, se eu crio um registro de CNAME de:

```
srvbr.meudominio.com IN CNAME srvbr.com
srveua.meudominio.com IN CNAME srveua.com
```

Quando alguém for resolver o DNS (browser, quem seja), endereço o ***srvbr.meudominio.com*** irá apontar para o ***srvbr.com***.

Com essa estratégia, você precisa configurar um domínio para cada servidor, isso é, precisa que cada servidor tenha um registro do tipo Address apontando para o IP. Segundo essa [pergunta do SO](https://serverfault.com/questions/377934/can-i-use-cname-with-ip-address-why-if-works-sometimes%29.), o CNAME não aceita valores do tipo **IP**.

No final teria algo como:

```
srvbr.com IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
svreua.com IN A yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

srvbr.dominio.com IN CNAME srvbr.com
srveua.dominio.com IN CNAME srveua.com
```

Exemplo prático:

**Eu** não tenho hospedagem para uma página pessoal minha, mas eu tenho um página pessoal no [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). O que eu faço: Criei um CNAME que aponta do meu domínio ***meudominio.com*** para o ***menunome.github.io***. Dado que eu não posso confiar no IP (registro do tipo A), que não está sobre meu controle.

**Se eu cometi algum erro teórico, me desculpem pois não sou extremo conhecedor de DNS. Fiquem a vontade para sugerir mudanças**

Algumas sugestões de leitura:

1. [CNAME_record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)
2. [entendendo-os-registros-de-dns-aaaa-ns](http://infotux.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/entendendo-os-registros-de-dns-aaaa-ns.html)
3. [differences-between-a-cname-alias-url](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/)
4. [cname-record](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/spry_menu/cname-record/)

Comment: Não entendi, para funcionar eu não teria que colocar: `srveua.dominio.com` IN CNAME `ns1.abcdefgh.com` e `srveua.dominio.com` IN CNAME `ns2.abcdefgh.com` esse exemplo que fiz, é somente para o subdomínio srveua.dominio.com

Comment: Isso, eu me confundi com sua pergunta. Achei que eram ns1 e ns2, um para o servidor eua e outro pro servidor br. Mas acho que entendeu o conceito, onde tem um subdomínio que aponta para outro domínio.

Comment: No caso eu tenho que colocar o `IP` do servidor no registro do tipo `[A]`, e depois criar dois `CNAMES` iguais, mudando apenas ns1. e ns.2 ? Aí eu consigo transformar o subdomínio em um "domínio" e apontá-lo para outro servidor? :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, se os seus servidores já possuem domínio, não precisa criar o registro `[A]`, só se quiser. Apenas o de CNAME basta.

Answer (score -3):

Eu faço isso em várias ocasiões e sempre dá certo com o registro.br, usando o dns deles para fazer apontamento de Registro A. Ainda não consegui com o .com comprado junto a Godaddy, pois o painel deles me pareceu confuso e simplesmente não funciona como o esperado. Pelo menos para mim.

Faço exatamente como o colega sugeriu acima, exceto que não uso cname, pois não me parece necessário, uma vez que tenho dois ips comprados um em um servidor e o outro em outro.

srvbr.com IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
svreua.com IN A yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Comment: A resposta em questão não abrange de forma eficiente a pergunta, deixando espaços para duvidas e interpretações diferentes. Em suas respostas tente ser objetivo e claro, acredito que a sua resposta estaria melhor como comentário.